# debugfs on a NAS

Tags: devices, nas, debugfs

`# debugfs -R 'stat <INODE>' /dev/sdaX` or `# debugfs -R 'stat FILENAME' /dev/sdaX>` display file creation time etc.

How to run this command if the DEVICE is a NAS mounted e.g. on /MOUNTPOINT/VOL-1 with address 192.168.1.1:/VOL-1 ?

Comment: `debugfs` is meant to be used localy.

you NAS seems to be exporting NFS share, if you want to debug file access and stat you should connect to it using either GUI (likely) or some command line tools (very unlikely).

If you want information (beyond `ls`) about a particular file just use `stat FILE`

Comment: @Archemar - Thanks, `# stat FILENAME` displays ctime, atime & mtime, but not the birth or creation time (crtime).  But this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Could you find any solution to get the creation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Archemar already mentioned, `debugfs` may not work on a NFS-share.  However, you can access the NAS via `ssh USERNAME@NAS-IP` and execute `debugfs` and `stat` locally on your NAS.  Depending on its OS and the versions of the respective command you may get the requested information.  Unfortunately in my case, the NAS does not store the creation time, I only get Access, Modify and Change but no Birth time.

@Ali Tou:  I hope you have more luck than me!